# Why is my render distorted? Cylinder changes shape and loses colour when pressing F12 to render in Blender

Tags: modeling, rendering, image, distort

When I render this image with <kbd>F12</kbd>, my cylinder becomes very distorted, as you can see here. This is my first attempt in Blender.

[image: cylinder has become distorted and lost colour when rendering using F12]

Comment: Hello please share your file